# I'm trying to push the created file to git repo and it is returning Error Code 403

Tags: git, ubuntu, github, command-line

I just created a new repo in Git and copied the repository link.

```
1. came to ubuntu terminal generated clone by using command "git clone repo-link" 
2. git init
3. mkdir Jesse ,new file created
4. cd Jesse
5. git init
6. git remote add origin repo-link,2nd point link
7. touch index.html
8. git add index.html
9. git commit -m "new HTML file added"
10. git push -u origin master
11. username: entered password: I copied my personal access token, then I have these error
Username for 'https://github.com': Hemanthkumar
Password for 'https://Hemanthkumar@github.com':
remote: Permission to Hemanthrapata/Everest.git denied to Hemanthrapata.

fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/Hemanthrapata/Everest.git/': The requested URL            returned error: 403
```

Please help me to sort out this problem step-by-step explanation

Comment: If you initially clone, you don't need to init.... but init twice?! Can you double-check there are no typos in your list of actions here?

Answer (score 1):

You mentioned that you copied a personal access token. When using a personal access token for authentication, make sure that the token has the necessary scopes to perform the actions you want (in this case, pushing to the repository).

Double-check if the access token that you have copied is correct and has necessary permissions. Attached image for your reference

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try this way :

```
git init
git add yourfiles
git commit -m "first commit"
git branch -M main
git remote add origin git@github.com:youraccount/yourrepo.git // copy ssh path
git push -u origin main
```